# How to display rate within a given date range(in the question below) using map in cpp?

Tags: c++, c++11

My question is:

```
Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20,1/25/20,1/26/20

,Afghanistan,33.0,65.0,0,0,0,0 
,Albania,41.1533,20.1683,0,0,0,0,0
,Algeria,28.0339,1.6596,0,0,0,0,0 
,Andorra,42.5063,1.5218,0,0,0,0,0 
,Angola,11.2027,17.8739,0,0,0,0,0 
New South Wales,Australia,33.8688,151.2093,10,0,20,0,0  
Northern Territory,Australia,-12.4634,130.8456,5,2,3,0,0
```

The above is a csv file.I have to read the country, start date and end date from the user     and print the rate values within that range?Also, I have to calculate the average of recovery rate per day in that country and print it. How can this be done?
If start date entered by user is 01/22/2020 and end date is 1/24/2020 and country is   Australia,
Expected result should be like:

```
Date           Rate
01/22/2020      7.5(10+5/2)
01/23/2020      1((0+2)/2)
01/24/2020      11.5((20+3)/2)
```

Comment: I would suggest using a CSV parsing library. Here's a [list](https://cpp.libhunt.com/categories/4963-csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it boils again down to parsing a CSV file into tokens.

First and most important, for regular CSV files, you never need a 3rd party library. Everthing is build in an easily usable.

Splitting a string into tokens is a very old task. There are many many solutions available. All have different properties. Some are difficult to understand, some are hard to develop, some are more complex, slower or faster or more flexible or not.

Alternatives

1. Handcrafted, many variants, using pointers or iterators,  maybe hard to develop and error prone.
2. Using old style `std::strtok` function. Maybe unsafe. Maybe should not be used any longer
3. `std::getline`. Most used implementation. But actually a "misuse" and not so flexible
4. Using **dedicated** modern function, **specifically** developed for this purpose, most flexible and good fitting into the STL environment and algortithm landscape. But slower.

Please see 4 examples in one piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
#include <forward_list>
#include <deque>

using Container = std::vector<std::string>;
std::regex delimiter{ "," };


int main() {

    // Some function to print the contents of an STL container
    auto print = [](const auto& container) -> void { std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::decay<decltype(*container.begin())>::type>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; };

    // Example 1:   Handcrafted -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Search for comma, then take the part and add to the result
        for (size_t i{ 0U }, startpos{ 0U }; i <= stringToSplit.size(); ++i) {

            // So, if there is a comma or the end of the string
            if ((stringToSplit[i] == ',') || (i == (stringToSplit.size()))) {

                // Copy substring
                c.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(startpos, i - startpos));
                startpos = i + 1;
            }
        }
        print(c);
    }

    // Example 2:   Using very old strtok function ----------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Split string into parts in a simple for loop
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
        for (char* token = std::strtok(const_cast<char*>(stringToSplit.data()), ","); token != nullptr; token = std::strtok(nullptr, ",")) {
            c.push_back(token);
        }

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 3:   Very often used std::getline with additional istringstream ------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Put string in an std::istringstream
        std::istringstream iss{ stringToSplit };

        // Extract string parts in simple for loop
        for (std::string part{}; std::getline(iss, part, ','); c.push_back(part))
            ;

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 4:   Most flexible iterator solution  ------------------------------------------------

    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };


        Container c(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
        //
        // Everything done already with range constructor. No additional code needed.
        //

        print(c);


        // Works also with other containers in the same way
        std::forward_list<std::string> c2(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});

        print(c2);

        // And works with algorithms
        std::deque<std::string> c3{};
        std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(c3));

        print(c3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Next. You specific task. Those tasks will be solved, by splitting a big task into smaller tasks and selecting the correct data structures.

The small parts can then easily implemented and used by the next bigger task.

So, we will define many simple functions to solve the problem.

For the input we will always override the extractor operator, so that we can use it with all kinds of input streams.

If we look at the csv file, then we see that we have some kind of header line and many record lines. All together, we have one data set.

This observation will lead to the definition of 3 basic data structures:

1. Header
2. Record
3. Dataset

For the dataset, we add an evaluation function that will print the result on the screen.

We will define an extractor operator for all classes.

The extractor for the Header, will read a line, spilt in into tokens, check, if the data is expected, converts the time strings to a `std::tm` and then stores all values. At the end, the empty line will be condumed.

This is for one line and totally straight forward.

The extractor for the Record is similar simple, same mechanism. Read a line, split it into tokens, make a sanity check and assign all values.

The extractor for the Dataset will call the other 2 extractors. One for the header, and then, in a loop, for all Records. All the read data will be stored in the internal data variables. We use a `std::map` for grouping, on the request of the OP, but not really necessary.

In the evealuation function, we first look for the dates in the header line on at which index they are for the given start and end date. We make a sanit check for the country name and the given dates. Then we iterate over the given country group and add up all values for the given date and ountry.

The resulting average will be shown on the display.

An additional helper function will read a date in a specified format from the user. Also rather stright forward.

And in main we implement some driver code.

First we read the complete csv file, which boils down to one statement.

By the consequent application of overwriting the extrator operators, we come up with the nice one-liner: `csvFile >> dataset;`

The we get the start and end date, and the country. We call our evaluating function and show the result.

By breaking down the initially big problem into smaller problems, we come to a really easy solution.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <map>

// This is the source file. It does not matter, whether it is a fstream or an istringstream. It will always work
std::istringstream csvFile{ R"(Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20,1/25/20,1/26/20

,Afghanistan,33.0,65.0,0,0,0,0 
,Albania,41.1533,20.1683,0,0,0,0,0
,Algeria,28.0339,1.6596,0,0,0,0,0 
,Andorra,42.5063,1.5218,0,0,0,0,0 
,Angola,11.2027,17.8739,0,0,0,0,0 
New South Wales,Australia,33.8688,151.2093,10,0,20,0,0  
Northern Territory,Australia,-12.4634,130.8456,5,2,3,0,0  )" };

// The delimiter in the CSV file
const std::regex re{ "," };

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data structures

// Header Line. We will only store the dates
struct Header {
    std::vector<std::tm> dates{};
};

// A data record, consiting of location information and rates
struct Record {
    std::string provinceState{};
    std::string countryRegion{};
    std::string latitude{};
    std::string longitude{};
    std::vector<double> rate{};
};

// A DataSet are a header and many Records
struct Dataset {
    // Heade line/data
    Header header;  

    // Reocrds, grouped by country
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<Record>> data;

    // This will generate the output for one dataset
    void showAverageRatePerCountryAndPeriod(const std::string& country, const std::tm& startDate, const std::tm& endDate);
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IO operations
// Overwriting the Extractor operator for each data struct

// Extractor operator for a Header line
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Header& h) {

    // Read a line from a stream, and check, if that worked
    std::string line{};
    if (std::getline(is, line)) {

        // Split string into tokens
        std::vector token(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {});

        // Sanity Check. Check for valid information in the header
        if ((token.size()) > 4 && (token[0] == "Province/State") && (token[1] == "Country/Region") && (token[2] == "Lat") && (token[3] == "Long")) {
        
            // Read all dates
            std::transform(token.begin() + 4, token.end(), std::back_inserter(h.dates), [](const std::string& s) {
                std::istringstream iss(s);  std::tm t{}; iss >> std::get_time(&t, "%m/%d/%y");  return t; });
        }
    }
    // Read the empty line after the header
    return std::getline(is, line);
}

// Extractor operator for one Record line
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Record& r) {

    // Read a line from a stream and check, if that worked
    if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

        // Split line into tokens
        std::vector token(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {});

        // Sanity Check. There must be enough data available
        if (token.size() > 4) {

            // Clear old data from previous invocation
            r.rate.clear();
            // Assign the string data
            r.provinceState = token[0]; r.countryRegion = token[1]; r.latitude = token[2]; r.longitude = token[3];

            // Copy the rate values
            std::transform(token.begin() + 4, token.end(), std::back_inserter(r.rate), [](const std::string& s) {
                return std::stod(s); });
        }
    }
    return is;
}

// Extractor Operator for a complete data set
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Dataset& d) {

    // Frist read the header
    if (is >> d.header) {

        // Clear aold data from previous reads
        d.data.clear();

        // Now read all Records. Line by line
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line) and not line.empty(); ) {

            // Put the line in a stringstream and the extract the dates from there
            std::istringstream iss{ line };
            if (Record r{}; iss >> r) 
                d.data[r.countryRegion].push_back(std::move(r));  // Store new record
        }
    }
    return is;
}

// This is a helper function for showing the expected results on the screen
void Dataset::showAverageRatePerCountryAndPeriod(const std::string& country, const std::tm& startDate, const std::tm& endDate) {

    // Do we have the given country name in ourt data set
    if (data.find(country) != data.end()) {

        // A simle Lambda for comparing 2 std::tm
        auto tmCompare = [](std::tm l, std::tm r) { return std::mktime(&l) < std::mktime(&r); };

        // Get the index of the start end end time in the vector fo dates
        int indexStart = std::distance(header.dates.begin(), std::lower_bound(header.dates.begin(), header.dates.end(), startDate, tmCompare));
        int indexEnd =   std::distance(header.dates.begin(), std::upper_bound(header.dates.begin(), header.dates.end(), endDate, tmCompare));

        // Sanity check for valid date information
        if (indexEnd - indexStart <= 0) {
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Wrong Dates\n";
        }
        else {
            // Show output to user
            std::cout << "\nDate\t\tRate\n";

            // Iterate through all rates for that date and country
            for (int indexDate = indexStart; indexDate < indexEnd; ++indexDate) {

                // Temporary for calculating the sum for one day for this country
                double sumForDay{};

                // For all records for this country
                for (const Record& r : data[country]) {
                    // Sum up, if data is available
                    if (indexDate < r.rate.size()) sumForDay += r.rate[indexDate];
                }
                // Show date and average on display
                std::cout << std::put_time(&header.dates[indexDate], "%m/%d/%Y") << '\t' << sumForDay / data[country].size() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n***Error: Country not found\n";
    }
}

// Helper function for reading a valid date
std::tm getDate(std::string&& userInstruction) {

    // Here we will store the result
    std::tm t{};

    // We will try to read data until we got something value from the user
    bool inputIsValid{ false };
    while (not inputIsValid) {

        // Give instructions
        std::cout << '\n' << userInstruction << "\nPlease use the format  mm/dd/yy:\t";

        // Read a complete line
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(std::cin, line)) {

            // Try to convert the string to a date
            std::istringstream iss{ line };
            if (iss >> std::get_time(&t, "%m/%d/%y")) inputIsValid = true;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
// Driver code
int main() {

    // Read a complete dataset from any stream
    Dataset dataset{};
    csvFile >> dataset;

    // Get the start and end date 
    std::tm startDate{ getDate("Please enter a start date.") };
    std::tm endDate  { getDate("Please enter an end date.") };

    // Read country from user
    std::cout << "\nEnter country: ";
    if (std::string country{}; std::cin >> country) {
        std::cout << '\n';

        // Evaluate and show result
        dataset.showAverageRatePerCountryAndPeriod(country, startDate, endDate);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Woah. Thanks a lot. I will try this out.